# How to load moodle stylesheet sourcemaps

Tags: css, moodle, source-maps

For stylesheets, am using the following line in the theme's config.php:

`$THEME->sheets = array('theme', 'custom');`

But how about loading the source map for that stylesheet which is a separate file?